# Why does $v \in \ker(A- \lambda I)^m$ imply that $Av$ is contained in $\ker(A- \lambda I)^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$ and an $n \times n$ matrix $A$,

Then why does $v \in \ker(A- \lambda I)^m$ imply that $Av$ is contained in  $\ker(A- \lambda I)^m$?

I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Infinite dimensional vector spaces are *not* isomorphic to their dual.

Comment: If you want to ask another question, ask another question. The original question was answered and you even accepted an answer. So the case should be closed. I've read people write: "please don't deface your question".

Answer (score 7):

This is essentially because $(A-\lambda I)^{m}$ and $A$ commute. Can you see this now?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier here to go for a more general fact: the kernel of *any* polynomial $P$ of $A$ is stable under $A$. Or even more general and closer to what you need in the proof: the kernel of any linear operator commuting with $A$ is stable under $A$. The same is also true if you replace "kernel" by "image" (the proof is slightly different, but equally straightforward).